# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery and I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of null" when I try to do the following.
   I'm trying to call a function that will check if value of my textbox is null and assign it zero, by calling the id of the function. I know I can assign directly, but there are so many of them, that I feel calling a function is the way to go.

Here's my code for it:

```
function Fn_Save {

    function Fn_NullConvertor(input1) {

        if (document.getElementById("input1").val == "") {
            document.getElementById("input1").val == 1;
        }
    }

    if (confirm("Save?")) {

        Fn_NullConvertor(txtNum_Tracks);
        var params = {
            Num_Tracks: $.trim($("#txtNum_Tracks").val())

        }

    }
}
```

Thanks for your time, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Generally this error means exactly what it says: you're tyring to get at some property or function of null. So apparently it cannot find your element with ID 'input1'.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mix up parameter and string value `input1` vs. `"input1"`?

Comment: I must say that there are so many errors here that you really ought to learn how to look in the javascript error console or debug console and track down the errors reported there.  Your code doesn't even parse correctly, much less ever run.  You would definitely be seeing errors in the error console.  We really ought to not have to tell you where errors are that are already listed for you in the browser debugging tools.

Answer (score 1):

There are 5 problems:

- The `Fn_Save` is missing `()`
- There is no element with `input1` id or your code is getting executed before DOM is ready.
- There is no `.val` property for `HTMLElement`. It is `.value`
- You are using `==` for assignment
- According to what I think, you are after, then

This:

```
    function Fn_NullConvertor(input1) {
        if (document.getElementById("input1").val == "") {
            document.getElementById("input1").val == 1;
        }
    }
```

Should be:

```
    function Fn_NullConvertor(input1) {
        if (document.getElementById(input1).value == "") {
            document.getElementById(input1).value = "1";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If `input1` is a parameter for an element ID, then you shouldn't have quotes around it. Also note that:

Input elements don't have a `val` property. The property is called "value".

To assign a value, you need to use the `=` operator, not `==`.

```
function Fn_NullConvertor(input1) {
    var el = document.getElementById(input1);

    if (!el) {
        throw Error("No element with the ID " + input1 + " was found.");
    }

    if (!el.value) {
        el.value = 1;
    }
}
```

Also, when you pass an ID into your function, the ID **should** have quotes around it:

```
Fn_NullConvertor("txtNum_Tracks");
```

Answer (score 0):

That error means an html element with an id of "input1" cannot be found.  You should check that you have something like `<input id="input1" type="text">` on your page.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `.value` since you call pure javascript.
if use jquery it should be `.val()`